# switchMap function does not execute the code inside it

Tags: angular, firebase, ionic-framework, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-storage

I'm trying to add an item into my firestore with a picture, since the base64 picture is greater than 2Mb, I'm using firestore to store the image and get the url to set the corresponding field.

To do so, I'm sending my item to firebase with an empty field for the picture, then, I'm sending the picture to firebase storage. until here everything is ok, but when I'm trying to get the download url and set it to my item, it does not work.

here is my code:

Here my page where i'm adding a new item into firestore.

```js
export class AddFoodPage implements OnInit {
...
  addFood() {
    this.setFood();
    this.foodService.addFood(this.food, this.foodPicture.base64).then(() => {
      this.presentAlert();
      this.tagList = [];
      this.ingredientList = [];
      this.addFoodForm.reset();
    });
  }
...

  private setFood() {
    this.food = this.addFoodForm.value;
    this.food.ingredientList = this.ingredientList;
    this.food.specials = this.tagList;

    this.foodPicture = this.imgService.getPicture();
    this.food.photoUrl = '';
  }
```

here my service for the item:

```js
export class FoodService {
  private foodCollection: AngularFirestoreCollection<FoodView>;

  constructor(
    private afs: AngularFirestore,
    private authService: AuthService,
    private storage: AngularFireStorage
  ) {
    this.foodCollection = this.afs.collection('food');
  }

  async addFood(food: FoodView, base64String: string) {
    this.authService.getUserData().subscribe((_user) => {
      food.cookerName = _user.displayName;
      food.cookerId = _user.uid;
      from(this.foodCollection.add(food)).subscribe((addedFood) =>
        this.uploadFoodImage(base64String, addedFood.id, food.cookerId)
      );
    });
  }

private uploadFoodImage(
    base64String: string,
    foodId: string,
    userId: string
  ) {
    const filePath = `foods/${userId}/${foodId}`;

    const fileRef = this.storage.ref(filePath);
    const task: AngularFireUploadTask = fileRef.putString(
      base64String,
      'base64',
      { contentType: 'image/png' }
    );

    return from(task).pipe(
      switchMap(
        (result) => {
          return fileRef.getDownloadURL();
        }
        // Upload Task finished, get URL to the image
      ),
      switchMap((photoUrl) => {
        // Set the URL to the food document
        const uploadPromise = this.afs
          .doc(`food/${foodId}`)
          .set(photoUrl, { merge: true });
        console.log(photoUrl);
        return from(uploadPromise);
      })
    );
  }
```

In the above code, the code in the switchMap function are not executed, and I don't understand why, do I miss something ? The picture is saved into firebase storage, but then the document is not update in firestore.

here is my food model:

```js
export class FoodView {
  fid: string;
  cookerId: string;
  cookerName: string;
  title: string;
  photoUrl: string;
  ingredientList: string[] = [];
  type: string;
  hasAllergen: boolean;
  specials: string[];
  origin: string;
  price: number;
  quantity: number;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can devide Observables into two different kinds: "hot" and "cold" observables. With hot observables you've got the source of the emitted values outside of the function that is represented by the observable.
Cold observables on the other hand create the source in its own function. So for a cold observable to emit any values the body has to run at least once.

In your example the `form(task)` seems to create a cold observable. So to first create the source of data, you need to call the function by subscribing to it.

To shorten it up: Just add an `.subscribe()` after your pipe.

```js
return from(task).pipe(
      switchMap(
        (result) => {
          return fileRef.getDownloadURL();
        }
        // Upload Task finished, get URL to the image
      ),
      switchMap((photoUrl) => {
        // Set the URL to the food document
        const uploadPromise = this.afs
          .doc(`food/${foodId}`)
          .set(photoUrl, { merge: true });
        console.log(photoUrl);
        return from(uploadPromise);
      })
    ).subscribe();
```

Comment: Thank you it works !! Now I have an other error but I think I know what it is, but the code in the switchMap are executed, thank you!

The error I get now is 
`core.js:6150 ERROR FirebaseError: Function DocumentReference.set() called with invalid data. Data must be an object, but it was: "https://firebasestor..." (found in document food/WLUpAjFiP7MLhoPjUfxh)`, I think it's because i'm setting just the photoUrl and not the entire object.

Comment: My best guess is, that the subscription adds one call of your switchmap in front of your response form firebase. If i am right, just add an `if(!photoUrl) { return}` infront